# Offline message are not coming to user for one to one chat

Tags: ios, chat, ejabberd, xmmp

**Case 1**

When user connect for first time.
It send the presence `available` to server. Chat works fine in  this case.

**Presence recieved :**

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="***a52ce0a@localhost/2169635904633549718426" to="***a52ce0a@localhost/2169635904633549718426"/
```

**Case 2**

When connection disconnect mostly due to internet.
On connecting to internet again. `XmmpStream` connect automatically as set initially. But now it is sending this presence response :

**Presence recieved(Three times this time.) :**

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/6962759452435694889430" to="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/6962759452435694889430"/>`

<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/2169635904633549718426" to="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/6962759452435694889430"><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/2169635904633549718426" stamp="2017-04-25T06:33:04.442Z"/></presence>


<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/2169635904633549718426" to="58fdb5192bd7c1205a52ce0a@localhost/6962759452435694889430" type="unavailable"/>    // Why unavailable automatically.
```

By observing the response, I guess it is now connected to diffrent session from the same user. So Offline message will not come to this.

Is this from *iOS* side or from *ejabbered* side?

Why it is creating different session on reconnection automatically. If it is not creating different session, **then why offline message  are not coming.**

Comment: which version of ejabberd you are using?  if latest you should use XEP-0013: Flexible Offline Message Retrieval for getting offline message.

Comment: I figured out the problem by checking user status on the server. As App can not send presence on no internet connection. So at the server side it is remaining online forever means no offline queue. And due this loss of messages. 

Any solution now?

Comment: you can enabled mod_ping for this issue. check  this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291862/user-is-still-online-although-user-is-not-connected-to-the-server-and-failed-to/42322168#42322168

Comment: also enable stream mangement  both client and server side.